# Date conversion to a different locale

Tags: java, android, date, locale

I am working on an `Android` project in which I'm implementing localization.

I'll be getting the locale and the time zone. Using this information, I have written the below code:

```
String []locale= User.getInstance().getLanguage().split("-");//Assume, locale[0]=hi, locale[1]=IN
Calendar choosenDate = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale(locale[0],locale[1]));
SimpleDateFormat Dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy",new Locale(locale[0],locale[1]));
Log.d("MY_APP","***********Newly converted date:"+Dformat.format(choosenDate.getTime()));
```

The log that I'm getting from the above code is:

```
**********Newly converted date:सितंबर 07 2016
```

So, basically the problem I'm facing is only the `"MMMM"` i.e: the month part is getting converted into the Locale specified (in above language it is Hindi(hi-IN)). However, the `"dd yyyy"` is not getting converted into Hindi.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or how can I make sure that even the dd and yyyy part also get converted to the specified locale.

Comment: `dd` as well as `yyyy` is a number. How should it be converted to specified locale?

Comment: @VladMatvienko: yes it must be converted to that specific locale

Comment: **How** should it be converted? Can you give an example?

Comment: @VladMatvienko: It must be concerted as shown in below answer that is: सितंबर ०७ २०१६ . But the below code and my code are the same but it doesn't work on android.

Comment: Please edit your question to show *exactly* what you expect or want. Give sample input, sample `Locale`, and sample of what you want as well as what you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Arabic versus Hindu styled numerals

Apparently you expected the digits to be converted from the Arabic style to the Hindu style, as seen in this [Wikipedia article on Arabic-Hindu numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). (Not that I know *anything* about this subject. Please forgive any inappropriate use of language/country/tradition terms here.)

[image: Image of variations on the Arabic-Hindu numerals (sourced from Wikipedia)]

Your Question does not make obvious that you were after the alternative style of numeral digits; please take more care when posting to Stack Overflow.

## Arabic style on Oracle Java 8

FYI, I ran the following code using the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes used in the Question. I get only the Arabic style of numerals.

I loop through an arbitrary collection of [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) objects. For each I loop through all four of [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) objects to specify the length of abbreviation to use in automatically localizing the output of the current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now ( z );

List<Locale> locales = new ArrayList<> ();
locales.add ( Locale.US );
locales.add ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
locales.add ( Locale.TAIWAN );
locales.add ( new Locale ( "hi" , "IN" ) );  // Hindi, India.
// locales.add ( new Locale ( "ar" , "MA" ) );  // Arabic, Morocco

EnumSet<FormatStyle> formatStyles = EnumSet.allOf ( FormatStyle.class );

for ( Locale locale : locales ) {
    System.out.println ( "—————" );
    System.out.println ( "Locale: " + locale );
    for ( FormatStyle formatStyle : formatStyles ) {
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( formatStyle ).withLocale ( locale );
        System.out.println ( String.format ( "%1$-" + 20 + "s" , "FormatStyle: " + formatStyle ) + "  →  " + zdt.format ( f ) );
    }
}
System.out.println ( "—————" );
```

When run on the Oracle implementation of Java SE 8 Update 102 on macOS.

```
—————
Locale: en_US
FormatStyle: FULL     →  Wednesday, September 7, 2016 6:46:00 PM EDT
FormatStyle: LONG     →  September 7, 2016 6:46:00 PM EDT
FormatStyle: MEDIUM   →  Sep 7, 2016 6:46:00 PM
FormatStyle: SHORT    →  9/7/16 6:46 PM
—————
Locale: fr_CA
FormatStyle: FULL     →  mercredi 7 septembre 2016 18 h 46 EDT
FormatStyle: LONG     →  7 septembre 2016 18:46:00 EDT
FormatStyle: MEDIUM   →  2016-09-07 18:46:00
FormatStyle: SHORT    →  16-09-07 18:46
—————
Locale: zh_TW
FormatStyle: FULL     →  2016年9月7日 星期三 下午06時46分00秒 EDT
FormatStyle: LONG     →  2016年9月7日 下午06時46分00秒
FormatStyle: MEDIUM   →  2016/9/7 下午 06:46:00
FormatStyle: SHORT    →  2016/9/7 下午 6:46
—————
Locale: hi_IN
FormatStyle: FULL     →  बुधवार, 7 सितंबर, 2016 6:46:00 अपराह्न EDT
FormatStyle: LONG     →  7 सितंबर, 2016 6:46:00 अपराह्न EDT
FormatStyle: MEDIUM   →  7 सितंबर, 2016 6:46:00 अपराह्न
FormatStyle: SHORT    →  7/9/16 6:46 अपराह्न
—————
```

## Mystery: Legacy classes perform differently than java.time classes

Strangely, when I use the exact source code from the Question, I too get the same output as that seen in [the Answer by Dac Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39366339/642706) with the [Hindu/Indian-style numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals).

So I simplified that code. That source code was extraneously instantiating a `java.util.Calendar` object when in fact a `java.util.Date` object was being formatted. So I deleted the `Calendar` entirely.

```
Locale l = new Locale ( "hi" , "IN" );

// java.time
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMMM dd uuuu" ).withLocale ( l );
System.out.println ( ZonedDateTime.now ().format ( f ) );

// Legacy date-time classes.
SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ( "MMMM dd yyyy" , l );
System.out.println ( dFormat.format ( new java.util.Date () ) );
```

> सितंबर 07 2016
>
> सितंबर ०७ २०१६

While I do not fully understand this behavior, it seems we can draw two conclusions based on the Android behavior of Zax, the Ubuntu Linux experience of Dac Saunders, and my experience on macOS:

- Android implementation of legacy date-time classes differs from that of Linux & macOS. In Android, Arabic-style digits while on Linux/macOS we get Hindu-style.
- The java.time classes give only Arabic-style digits, differing in behavior from the legacy classes they supplant where we get Hindu-style. Perhaps a bug report should be filed.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Comment: About your mistery, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it works:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        String []locale = {"hi", "IN"};
        Calendar choosenDate = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale(locale[0],locale[1]));
        SimpleDateFormat Dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy",new Locale(locale[0],locale[1]));
        System.out.println("MY_APP***********Newly converted date:"+ Dformat.format(choosenDate.getTime() ));
    }
}
```

Test:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:32790,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/dac/proj/javatest2016/out/production/javatest2016:/home/dac/Downloads/idea-IU-145.972.3/lib/idea_rt.jar Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:32790', transport: 'socket'
Hello World!
MY_APP***********Newly converted date:सितंबर ०७ २०१६
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:32790', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can please try the program [online](http://ideone.com/sqHiC6).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i do not see any difference in my code and yours.

Comment: I used Ubuntu Linux. Maybe you can list your available locales and what they write. You could write a loop that writes it. Is you target platform an emulated Android then maybe it had an incomplete table for hindu.

Answer (score 2):

### Why do formatters sometimes use Arabic sometimes Hindu digits?

The format engines behind `SimpleDateFormat` or [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (on Java 8) uses localized resources which are originally based the [Common Locale Date Repository (CLDR)](http://cldr.unicode.org/) data from [The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/). In older CLDR data (for example v17) we find as default numbering system for the language Hindi (iso-639-code hi):

```
<defaultNumberingSystem>deva</defaultNumberingSystem>
```

But the newest [CLDR-version v29 shows](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/29/summary/hi.html#5):

```
<defaultNumberingSystem>latn</defaultNumberingSystem>
```

The CLDR code words "deva" and "latn" represent the Hindu digits (starting at codepoint 0x966) resp. the Arabic digits 0-9. So the behaviour of the Java- or Android-platform depends on the version. Old versions of the platform use old data while newer versions use the updated CLDR-data. **For mobile phones, it is hard or even impossible to predict which data Android will really use.** Not every user is used to update the Android version, and sometimes the manufacturer manipulates the resources, too.

### Can the number system used by formatters be configured?

YES! I show three ways.

a) **java.text.SimpleDateFormat**

```
Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");

DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(hindi);
char required = '०'; // copied from your comment
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat();
dfs.setZeroDigit(required); // or any other zero digit like '0'
numberFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy", hindi);
sdf.setNumberFormat(numberFormat);
System.out.println("SimpleDateFormat: " + sdf.format(new Date())); // सितंबर २३ २०१६
```

b) **java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter** (on Android you could use [ThreetenABP](https://github.com/jakewharton/threetenabp) instead)

```
Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");

char required = '०'; // copied from your comment
DecimalStyle style = DecimalStyle.of(hindi).withZeroDigit(required);

DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd yyyy", hindi).withDecimalStyle(style);
System.out.println("java.time: " + LocalDate.now().format(dtf)); // सितंबर २३ २०१६
```

Note: This solution still uses the resources of the Android platform (for example looking for the month names in Android).

c) My library **[Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)** (manages its own independent i18n-resources)

```
Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");

ChronoFormatter<PlainDate> cf =
    ChronoFormatter.ofDatePattern("MMMM dd yyyy", PatternType.CLDR, hindi).with(
        Attributes.NUMBER_SYSTEM,
        NumberSystem.DEVANAGARI
    );
System.out.println("Time4A: " + cf.format(PlainDate.nowInSystemTime())); // सितंबर २३ २०१६
```